# Wiring smart switch

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch, light

I have two separate lights in my room with two switches in the same box and am upgrading to two smart switches. The switches I bought have a neutral and I don't seem to see them in the box. Can anyone tell me if there is a neutral in here? This is a newer home if that matters and also there is a red wire that is capped off (orange cap in picture) and not connected to anything. Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Switches do not have neutral on them. However the smart switches do, for the Smart part to work. Your neutral is in the top left corner.

Comment: The white cap with the white wires should be your neutral.  Red is used for hot/live wires

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are in luck. The big group of white wires on the left of your picture are your neutrals. They need to remain hooked up together. You can see the bare ground wires  twisted together in the back of the box. You'll be able to trace your always hot wires back to the group on the right. If you ever run into the painter that did the house, thank them for painting the inside of the junction box. :-)

Comment: I see it now, my apologies, it looked like one of the white wires in the bubdle led to the switch since they painted over the wires and I just assumed it was not neutral. Thank you everyone that answered

Answer (score 2):

**WARNING**

Be careful what you are doing, you are not very experienced with electricity, and it can kill you.

On top, someone spray painted the wires in the box and now they all look white.

Here are your neutrals

[image: neutrals]

Also that neutral nut, is probably at its capacity (it already has 4 wires). So adding two more might be a problem. Get a bigger nut, or splice one of the neutrals.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact you are right, I mixed it up